# OutOfMemoryException when updating a large list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a large list and I would like to overwrite one value if required. To do this, I create two subsets of the list which seems to give me an `OutOfMemoryException`. Here is my code snippet:

```
if (ownRG != "")
{
    List<string> maclist = ownRG.Split(',').ToList();
    List<IVFile> temp = powlist.Where(a => maclist.Contains(a.Machine)).ToList();
    powlist = powlist.Where(a => !maclist.Contains(a.Machine)).ToList(); // OOME Here
    temp.ForEach(a => { a.ReportingGroup = ownRG; });
    powlist.AddRange(temp);
}
```

Essentially I'm splitting the list into the part that needs updating and the part that doesn't, then I perform the update and put the list back together. This works fine for smaller lists, but breaks with an `OutOfMemoryException` on the third row within the `if` for a large list. Can I make this more efficient?

**NOTE**
`powlist` is the large list (>1m) items. `maclist` only has between 1 and 10 but even with 1 item this breaks.

Comment: You can start by removing unnecessary `ToLists` and arrange your code accordingly.

Comment: @ EZI: which one is unnecesary? the first to list creates a sublist with the items I want to change. The second is to remove the items that changed from the original list. Is this not what I m doing? sorry I m a beginner...

Comment: I'm assuming `powlist` is the large list?

Comment: yes exactly Ryan, maclist only contains less then 10 items

Comment: @nik **1)** *Split* returns an array, you don't have to convert it to List (x2 memory) **2)** Just be able to use `ForEach`, you don't have to convert `temp` to List. Leave it as `IEnumerable` and use a classical *foreach* loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create a bunch of sub-lists from `powlist` and reconstruct it.  Simply loop over the `powlist` and update the `ReportingGroup` property accordingly.

```
var maclist = new HashSet<string>( ownRG.Split(',') );
foreach( var item in powlist) {
    if( maclist.Contains( item.Machine ) ){
        item.ReportingGroup = ownRG;
    }
}
```

Since this changes `powlist` in place, you won't allocate any extra memory and shouldn't run into an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: thank you. simple and works! what is the advantage of hashset<string>?

Comment: The [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't require looping over the items to determine if it `Contains` a specific item.  It has constant-time performance.  It's hard to say whether or not it would be more efficient given the small size of `maclist`, but since the `Contains` call occurs for each of the >1m items, it's likely faster (but it's hard to say definitively without timing it).

Answer (score 1):

### Solving your issue

Here is how to rearrange your code using the enumerator code from my answer:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ownRG))
{
    var maclist = new CommaSeparatedStringEnumerable(str);
    var temp = powlist.Where(a => maclist.Contains(a.Machine));

    foreach (var p in temp)
    {
        p.ReportingGroup = ownRG;
    }
}
```

- You should not use `ToList` in your code.
- You don't need to remove thee contents of `temp` from `powlist` (you are re-adding them anyway)

### Streaming over a large comma-separated string

You can iterate over the list manually instead of doing what you do now, by looking for `,` characters and remembering the position of the last found one and the one before. This will definitely make your app work because then it won't need to store the entire set in the memory at once.

Code example:

```
var str = "aaa,bbb,ccc";
var previousComma = -1;
var currentComma = 0;

for (; (currentComma = str.IndexOf(',', previousComma + 1)) != -1; previousComma = currentComma)
{
    var currentItem = str.Substring(previousComma + 1, currentComma - previousComma - 1);
    Console.WriteLine(currentItem);
}
var lastItem = str.Substring(previousComma + 1);
Console.WriteLine(lastItem);
```

### Custom iterator

If you want to do it 'properly' in a fancy way, you can even write a custom enumerator:

```
public class CommaSeparatedStringEnumerator : IEnumerator<string>
{
    int previousComma = -1;
    int currentComma = -1;
    string bigString = null;
    bool atEnd = false;

    public CommaSeparatedStringEnumerator(string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");

        bigString = s;
        this.Reset();
    }

    public string Current { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose() { /* No need to do anything here */ }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return this.Current; } }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (atEnd)
            return false;

        atEnd = (currentComma = bigString.IndexOf(',', previousComma + 1)) == -1;

        if (!atEnd)
            Current = bigString.Substring(previousComma + 1, currentComma - previousComma - 1);
        else
            Current = bigString.Substring(previousComma + 1);

        previousComma = currentComma;
        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        previousComma = -1;
        currentComma = -1;
        atEnd = false;
        this.Current = null;
    }
}

public class CommaSeparatedStringEnumerable : IEnumerable<string>
{
    string bigString = null;

    public CommaSeparatedStringEnumerable(string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");

        bigString = s;
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CommaSeparatedStringEnumerator(bigString);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate over it like this:

```
var str = "aaa,bbb,ccc";
var enumerable = new CommaSeparatedStringEnumerable(str);

foreach (var item in enumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

### Other thoughts

> Can I make this more efficient?

Yes, you can. I suggest to either work with a more efficient data format (you can take a look around databases or XML, JSON, etc. depending on your needs). If you really want to work with comma-separated items, see my code examples above.

Comment: so you are saying instead of splitting the list I should just iterate over the entire list with string replace?

Comment: @nik No, not string replace. Look at my example code.

Comment: This is a nice way to stream over a comma-delimited list, but OP's problem is not with the split (despite the question's title).

Comment: Yeah, obviously, he shouldn't use `ToList` (as the others also said)

Comment: @Ryan I edited my answer and added how the code should be changed to be more efficient.

Comment: @Venemo Removed my downvote ;-)  I do think this is a bit overly-complicated since the `string.Split` wasn't at issue, but it's still a well constructed answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a loop find the next ',' char.  Take the substring between the ',' and the previous ',' position.  At the end of the loop save a reference to the previous ',' position (which is initially set to 0).  So you parse the items one-by-one rather than all at once.

Answer (score -2):

You can try looping the items of your lists, but this will increase processing time.

```
foreach(var item in powlist)
{
//do your opeartions
}
```

Comment: Care to state why negative votes? As I see, the accepted solution and what I offered are the same...